# Sequelize returns null for Postgres 'timestamp with time zone' columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and am having trouble getting `timestamp` data from a Postgres database. Everything I have tried so far returns `null` for all `timestamp` fields.

Below are the Postgres definitions for the columns in question:

```
created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
updated_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
```

These are all the different ways I've attempted to define the relevant portion of the model in Node.js (tried the same things for updated_date):

```
created_date: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false
},
created_date: {
  type: 'TIMESTAMP',
  defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
  allowNull: false
},
created_date: {
  type: 'timestamp with time zone',
  defaultValue: sequelize.literal('current_timestamp'),
  allowNull: false
},
created_date: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
```

For all combinations the Sequelize `timestamp` attribute has been set to `false` (because we are handling them manually). I've tried to change this value to `true` as well with no success.

Lastly, the query is structured like so (notice the two different ways I've attempted to access the columns below):

```
data = await <MyModel>.findAll({
  order: [['created_date', 'DESC']],
  attributes: [
    'id',
    ['created_date', 'createdDate'],
    [models.sequelize.col('<my_table>.updated_date'), 'updatedDate'],
    ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

All attempts have returned `null` for both `timestamp` values from the database. I have verified that the `timestamp` values in the database do exist and are not `null`. And, all other database values are being returned as expected.

Using Sequelize `v5.9.4`

Any help tracking down the root cause of this issue will be greatly appreciated. I've spent way too many hours trying to figure this one out. Thanks in advance!

Edit - More information that may be relevant:

The following is the metadata that is returned from running a raw query through Sequelize:

```
 Field {
   name: 'created_date',
   tableID: XXXXX,
   columnID: XX,
   dataTypeID: 1184,
   dataTypeSize: 8,
   dataTypeModifier: -1,
   format: 'text' },
 Field {
   name: 'updated_date',
   tableID: XXXXX,
   columnID: XX,
   dataTypeID: 1184,
   dataTypeSize: 8,
   dataTypeModifier: -1,
   format: 'text' },
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the logging parameter to true on the sequelize object to see what it sends? Then you can copy/paste the exact query in phAdmin to make sure it runs as you expect.

Comment: @VictorP thanks for the suggestion! I'm looking through the logs now.

Comment: @VictorP the query executes and returns the data as expected in the Postgres query tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the solution my team landed on after a few days of head scratching and pouring over the Sequelize documentation. It requires casting the `timestamp` to a `string` and using `moment` to handle the date and time manually in JavaScript. I'm not posting the `moment` portion of the fix here, but the way we cast the `timestamp` to a `string` is as follows:

```
const data = await <MyModel>.findAll({
  order: [['created_date', 'DESC']],
  attributes: [
    'id',
    [sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('<my_table>.created_date'), 'String'), 'createdDate'],
    [sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('<my_table>.updated_date'), 'String'), 'updatedDate'],
    ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

Hopefully this saves someone else some time in the future!

Answer (score 2):

You can change DateStyle only into your session. After connect:

when use typeorm you can get PG Pool like this e add a listener on connect event. You can search how get pg driver in Sequelize and do it.

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import { PostgresDriver } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresDriver';

if (connection.driver instanceof PostgresDriver) {
    const pool = connection.driver.master as Pool;
    pool.on('connect', (client) => {
      client.query('SET DATESTYLE = iso, mdy');
    });
}
```

So you can keep your database with current configuration e resolve you problem with dates.

Comment: I had a similar issue when querying dates (timestamp without timezone), pg client returned null for all dates. I was able to fix it by adding client.query('SET DATESTYLE = iso, mdy');. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize will add timestamps by default. Maybe you have to tell it not to use those defaults before you can use yours:

```
// remove defaults
createdAt: false,
updatedAt: false,
// declare mine
created_date: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: false
},
updated_date: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE
  defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  allowNull: true
},
```

For reference

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#configuration

Comment: Thank you for your response. This doesn't seem to solve my problem, but I agree that it's likely there is some interference between the default functionality of Sequelize and our manual implementation. Unfortunately we are working with an existing database, or I may have decided to allow Sequelize to handle the Timestamps for us.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your problem and solution: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/471

Sequelize works on top of pg, and pg does not know how to parse the non-iso date.
Check your postgresql.conf file, what is your date format?

Try this: `datestyle = 'iso, dmy'`

(restart service to apply)